# Deserialized object not same as source

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xmlserializer

I'm having problem deserializing previously serialized XML.

My class is generated from .xsd by xsd.exe utility. I have no influence on the structure of .xsd as it was issued by government, and used to standardize communication...

The problem is, when I create an object, set some properties on it, then serialize it using XmlSerializer, and then deserialize it back, I do not get the same "contents" as I started with. Some of the elements from XML deserialize in "Any" property instead of properties from which these elements were serialized in a first place.

Perhaps a clumsy explanation, but I've created a sample project that reproduces my issue.
Sample project can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4412647/XmlSerializerBugReproduce.zip).

Edit:
Ok, here is some sample code. Unfortunately I can't paste everything here, because file generated by xsd.exe is over 4000 lines long. But everything required is in linked file.

My test console app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Pismeno pismeno = new Pismeno();

        #region Build sample content
        pismeno.Sadrzaj = new SadrzajTip();
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml("<SomeXml xmlns=\"http://some.namespace.com/\">Some content goes here</SomeXml>");
        pismeno.Sadrzaj.Item = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;

        pismeno.Prilog = new PismenoPrilog[1];
        pismeno.Prilog[0] = new PismenoPrilog();
        pismeno.Prilog[0].VrijemeNastanka = DateTime.Now.ToString("s");

        XmlDocument xmlTitle = new XmlDocument();
        xmlTitle.LoadXml("<Title xmlns=\"http://some.namespace.com/\">Test title 1</Title>");
        pismeno.Prilog[0].Any = new XmlElement[1];
        pismeno.Prilog[0].Any[0] = xmlTitle.DocumentElement;

        pismeno.Prilog[0].Sadrzaj = new SadrzajTip();
        EAdresaTip eat = new EAdresaTip();
        eat.URL = "http://www.example.com/testfile.doc";
        pismeno.Prilog[0].Sadrzaj.Item = eat;
        #endregion

        // Serialize object, and then deserialize it again
        string pismenoSer = Serialize(pismeno);
        Pismeno pismeno2 = Deserialize<Pismeno>(pismenoSer);

        // Objects to compare. "source" has source.Sadrzaj and source.Prilog properties set
        // "shouldBeTheSameAsSource" has shouldBeTheSameAsSource.Any property set
        Pismeno source = pismeno;
        Pismeno shouldBeTheSameAsSource = pismeno2;
    }

    public static string Serialize(object o)
    {
        string ret = null;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            XmlWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };

            new XmlSerializer(o.GetType()).Serialize(xw, o);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            ret = (new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8)).ReadToEnd();
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
    {
        return (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)));
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to show some code. Very few people are going to blindly follow the link you posted.

Comment: Are you defining the Any property with XmlAnyElementAttribute in your Pismeno type?

Comment: Yes, chunk of code that was generated looks like this; `        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
        public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any {
            get {
                return this.anyField;
            }
            set {
                this.anyField = value;
            }
        }`